# Lua - It is possible to define structs with ProtoField?

Tags: lua, wireshark

I'm trying to write my own dissector.
I read:

[1](http://csjark.readthedocs.org/en/latest/user/config.html#unknown-structs-handling): http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/ and the [Unknown structs handling](http://csjark.readthedocs.org/en/latest/user/config.html#unknown-structs-handling) section of the `CSjark` documentation.

And I didnt found a way to use ProtoField  with structs:

For example, I want to write dissector for the following ICD:

```
int32 syncWord
int16 size
int16 num_of_structs

strcut_1
strcut_2
....
struct_n
```

where Struct has the follwoing members:

```
int32 x
int32 y
int32 z
```

When building the messages I can write:

```
msg.syncWord= ProtoField.int32 ("myproto.syncWord", "syncWord")
msg.size= ProtoField.int16 ("myproto.size", "size")
msg.num_of_structs= ProtoField.int16 ("myproto.num_of_structs", "num_of_structs")
```

My problem is how can I add the structs ?
Is there an convient way ? (or just duplicate the structs fields again and again ?)
I cant found any member of structs for ProtoField...
Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0):

In ask.wireshark.org was asked similar question that have useful answer: https://ask.wireshark.org/questions/28038/how-to-create-a-protofield-sub-array-in-lua

And you can read (Chapter 10. Lua Support in Wireshark) documentation for Wireshark dissector development, probably there you will find some good advices: https://www.wireshark.org/docs/wsdg_html_chunked/wslua_dissector_example.html